# Bias-Variance decomposition of sample average estimator.

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, machine-learning, variance

I want to find the bias and variance of regularized mean estimator which is 
$$h_{\lambda}(D) \leftarrow \underset{m}{argmin} \ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^N |Y_i - m |^2 + \lambda m^2 $$
$$ h_{\lambda }(D) = \frac{1}{N + \lambda} \sum_{i = 1}^N Y_i$$
$Y$ is a random variable with known distribution and $Y_i$ are independent and 
$E(Y) = \mu$, $Var(Y) = \sigma^2$ and $D = \{Y_1, Y_2, . . ., Y_n\}$

since bias and variance is defined as 
$$\mathbb{E}_D \left[ |h(D) - \mu |^2 \right] = \underbrace{|\mathbb{E}_D[h(D)] - \mu|^2}_{Bias} + \underbrace{\mathbb{E}_D \left[|h(D) - \mathbb{E}_D [h(D)]|^2 \right]}_{variance} $$

So my approach is $h_{\lambda}(D) = \bar{Y}$ and $E(\bar{Y}) = \mu$ So bias would be $|\frac{\mu}{\lambda} -\mu|^2 = \frac{\mu^2(1 - \lambda)^2}{\lambda^2}$

but this does not seem correct. What is the correct way of doing it?

Thank you.

Comment: First check expression for $h_\lambda(D)$. It is not equal to what you wrote.

Comment: @NCh I took derivative w. r. t 'm' and then set it equal to zero and then worked out m, seems correct to me...unless you can point a mistake.

Comment: I cannot point a mistake since you did not show your calculations. Check the derivative.

Comment: $$h \leftarrow \underset{m}{argmin} \ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^N |Y_i - m |^2 + \lambda m^2 $$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m} = \sum_{i = 0}^N \frac{\partial}{\partial m}(Y_i- m)^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial m} \lambda m^2$$
$$ = \sum_{i = 1}^N 2(Y_i - m) + 2\lambda m$$
setting the derivative equal to zero
$$ 0 = \sum_{i = 1}^N 2(Y_i - m) + 2\lambda m$$
$$ 0 = \sum_{i = 1}^N (Y_i - m) + \lambda m$$
$$0 = \sum_{i = 1}^N Y_i- m(N+\lambda)$$
$$ (N + \lambda) m = \sum_{i = 1}^N Y_i$$
$$ m = \frac{1}{N + \lambda} \sum_{i = 1}^N Y_i$$
So
$$ h = \frac{1}{N + \lambda} \sum_{i = 1}^N Y_i$$

Comment: Where is $\frac1N$ under the sum? Also you lost minus sign in the derivative of a sum.

Comment: @PureEvil is this for 311?

Comment: @ph-quiett ping me on Reddit if you wanna talk u/RED-_-X, comments not related to question are usually removed by mods

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i = 1}^N (Y_i - m)^2 + \lambda m^2\right)=-\frac2N\sum_{i = 1}^N (Y_i - m) + 2m\lambda =0$$
$$
-\frac2N\sum_{i = 1}^N Y_i + \frac2N\cdot mN + 2m\lambda =0
$$
$$
2m(1+\lambda)=\frac2N\sum_{i = 1}^N Y_i
$$
$$
m=\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\cdot \bar Y = h_\lambda(D)
$$
$$
\mathbb E[h_\lambda(D)] = \frac{1}{1+\lambda} \mathbb E[\bar Y] = \frac{1}{1+\lambda} \mathbb E[Y_1] = \frac{1}{1+\lambda} \mu.
$$
So bias is 
$$
\mathbb E[h_\lambda(D)] - \mu = \frac{1}{1+\lambda} \mu - \mu = -\frac{\lambda\mu}{1+\lambda}
$$
Please check the definitions. Bias of an estimate $\theta^*$ of parameter $\theta$ is $\mathbb E[\theta^*]-\theta$, nothing else.

Next, 
$$
\text{Var}(h_\lambda(D)) = \text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\cdot \bar Y\right) = \frac{1}{(1+\lambda)^2} \text{Var}(\bar Y) = \frac{1}{(1+\lambda)^2} \frac{\text{Var}(Y_1)}{N}.
$$